# Set two unrelated ranges in one variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables, range, runtime-error

I have 2 unrelated ranges (С3:D5,F3:G5). I want to set them in one variable (A).
Error ‘1004’ pops up . Is it possible at all ? And if so , how to do it ?

```
     Sub пг()
     Dim book1 As Workbook
     Dim book2 As Workbook
     Dim A As String

    'C3:D5
    'F3:G5

     A = "C3:D5&F3:G5"

     Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 6\Процесс создания\Индекс формы команды\Вспомогательные проги\пг\1.xlsx")
     Set book2 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 6\Процесс создания\Индекс формы команды\Вспомогательные проги\пг\2.xlsx")

    'по листам

     book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Activate
     Range("" + A + "").Copy
     book2.Worksheets("Лист1").Activate
     Range("" + A + "").Select
     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll


     book1.Close


     End Sub
```

Comment: `A = "C3:D5&F3:G5"` should be `A = "C3:D5,F3:G5"` but the copy/paste won't work with non-contiguous ranges.  Just do two copy/pastes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim book1 As Workbook, book2 As Workbook
    Dim rng

    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 6\Процесс создания\Индекс формы команды\Вспомогательные проги\пг\1.xlsx")
    Set book2 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 6\Процесс создания\Индекс формы команды\Вспомогательные проги\пг\2.xlsx")

    For Each rng In Range("C3:D5,F3:G5").Areas
        book2.Worksheets("Лист1").Range(rng.Address).Value = book2.Worksheets("Лист1").Range(rng.Address).Value
    Next rng
End Sub
```

***Note :*** Above code will only paste values.

Comment: I gave +1, but you got the order of the books reversed, it should be `book2.. = book1...`

Answer (score 2):

Copy/paste will not work on a non-contiguous range.  You will need to do it in two steps:

```
Sub пг()
    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim book2 As Workbook

    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 6\Процесс создания\Индекс формы команды\Вспомогательные проги\пг\1.xlsx")
    Set book2 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 6\Процесс создания\Индекс формы команды\Вспомогательные проги\пг\2.xlsx")

    'по листам
    book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Range("C3:D5").Copy book2.Worksheets("Лист1").Range("C3:D5")
    book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Range("F3:G5").Copy book2.Worksheets("Лист1").Range("F3:G5")

    book1.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm also watching ;)

Comment: I finally got that Excel-VBA Gold badge, now I have the "Power" :)

Comment: @ShaiRado No evil mwahaha?  You are obviously just pretending to be a benevolent despot, and hiding your actual plan to take over the world.

Comment: LOL , it's mwa, mwa, mwa, mwahaha... and so on (you get it)